# Convert LPVOID to CComVariant

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, atl

I have following Win32 ATL code:

```
CComVariant result;
DWORD dwFileSize = GetFileSize(hFile, NULL);
LPVOID lpBuffer = HeapAlloc(hHeap, NULL, dwFileSize + 1);
ReadFile(hFile, lpBuffer, dwFileSize, &bytesReaded, NULL)
```

Now I need to put the value of lpBuffer to result variable. How can I do it?

Comment: What type of variant do you want to create?

Comment: String. But result = (BSTR)lpBuffer doesn't give me valid string from file, but some gibberish text

Comment: Create an instance of the CComBSTR with the constructor that takes a LPCSTR as argument. Then use this instance in the constructor of CComVariant which takes a reference to a CComBSTR as an argument.

Answer (score 2):

A void* pointer is not a permitted data type for variants.  The closest natural match is an array of bytes.  You can use the CComSafeArray class wrapper to create one for element type VT_U1, the CComVariant(SAFEARRAY*) constructor to create the variant.  You'll probably want to call SafeArrayCreateDiscriptor and SafeArrayAllocData directly so that you can avoid having to copy the buffer.  Just read directly into the allocated data buffer.